# Deployment Queue is not displaying my default on-prem build agent

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management, azure-devops

I have installed my build agent on an azure VM, and configure to look at Visual Studio Online collection for Release Management to pick. I have configured it to run as a service, and I can see my agent under Default Queue
`https://{youraccount}.visualstudio.com/{collection}/_admin/_AgentQueue?queueId=1&_a=agents`, as green and Idle.

When I go to my environment, select Agent Queue, the drop down only shows the Hosted option. 
What are the requirements for an agent to be shown in the dropdown? Any ports, permissions/initial kick?

Note1: Securitywise, Agent Queues\Agent Queues Administrators is in the admin role of the Default Queue, and Agent Pools\Agent Pools Administrators are in the admin role of the Default Pool.

Note2: The service on the VM is running without any error logs..
The diag folder C:\agent_diag has logs similar to:

```
13:24:03.026012 MessageQueueListener.DispatchAsync - Getting message from Session: 628574c1-23a8-4a3b-a064-bbbdbe6ee806  
13:24:53.052407 MessageQueueListener.DispatchAsync - message received.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding your account to "Agent Queue Users" or "Agent Queue Administrators" group via following steps:

1. Open queue settings from "Settings\Control Panel\Default Collection\Agent Queues".
2. Select "Default (Default)" queue.
3. Select "Roles".
4. Select "Agent Queue Administrators" or "Agent Queue Users" group.
5. Click "Add" button and enter your account.
6. Save the changes.

Now you can go to Release Management and click the "Refresh" button on environment agent queue configure dialog to see if the default queue is listed now.

Comment: In my case, I don't see any groups under "roles", so I can't select "Agent Queue Administrators", how can that happen?

Comment: @EduardoWada Can you post a new question and add the screenshot so that we can check and help.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Sure, this is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023523/access-denied-when-creating-tfs-release-definition/41033314