# Access denied when creating TFS Release definition

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-security

I'm trying to setup a release definition on TFS but I'm running into an access denied message:

[image: Access denied message]

I thought I should have this permission, since I am part of the "Agent Pool Administrator" group:

[image: Agent Pool Administrator]

I noticed however, that my queue has no roles, and that I can't add one for some reason, which I suspect to be the related to the problem:

[image]

My question is how do I correctly configure the permissions? I've already googled a bunch but I still couldn't pinpoint what exact permission I'm missing.

**[[Update]]**

This is TFS 2015 update 3

Apparently, I am myself a project collection administrator already, but still don't have queue permissions and don't know, or can't see where to add myself as a queue admin.

[image: Project collection security tab]

The said queue was created by me, but indirectly, I created the agent pool with the auto-provision queues checked, and that created the queue, however, if I try to directly create a queue, I run into another "Access Denied" error

[image: Can't create queue]

**[Update]**

Trying to run `tfssecurity /collection:http://wada-pc:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /g+ "[Agent Queues]\Agent Queue Administrators" "domain\account"`

Leads me into `Error: Access Denied: Eduardo Wada needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Edit collection-level information`

However, I should have that permisison:

[image: Permissions screenshot]
[image: Permissions from TFS]

Comment: Which exact TFS version? In 2015, the Project Collection Administrator must add you as a Queue admin or a Queue user. In 2017 that moved to the project level an a Project Admin should be able to add you.

Comment: What's the status of the agents under TestPool agent Queue?

Comment: There's a single agent (Agent1) under TestPool agent queue and its status is "Idle"

Comment: Can you run this command and then check what happen: tfssecurity /collection:tfscollectionurl /g+ "[Agent Queues]\Agent Queue Administrators" "doamin\account"

Comment: I ran it like this: tfssecurity /collection:http://wada-pc:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/project1 /g+ "[Agent Queues]\Agent Queue Administrators" "domain\account"

Comment: And got this: The target Team Foundation Server is http://wada-pc:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/project1.
TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: http://wada-pc:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/project1.
Team Foundation Server Url: http://wada-pc:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/project1.

Possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

Technical information (for administrator):
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not

Comment: You need to remove the "project1" from the url

Comment: Now I got `Error: Access Denied: Eduardo Wada needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Edit collection-level information`. However, I should have that one, I added another screenshot into the question.

Comment: @EduardoWada Is the permission also set to Allow if you check it from TFS Web Portal: "Control Panel>DefaultCollection\Security\Users"?

Comment: From TFS, "Edit collection-level information" doesn't appear in the list, but for all permissions listed I have "Inherited Allow"

Comment: What permission list you get on that screen?

Comment: Added to the end of the question

Comment: You are checking the security from project level, please check the security from collection level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130477/discussion-between-eddie-msft-and-eduardo-wada).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your issue is related to the agent queue roles. An agent queue provides access to a pool of agents. Usually, there are two groups under the Roles:

**Agent Queue Administrators**: People in this group can register new agents in that pool, add users to the Agent Pool Service Accounts and add other administrators to the pool.

**Agent Queue Users**: For Team Foundation Server the service account you specify for the agent (commonly Network Service) is automatically added when you register the agent.

[image]

Try to use the account that create this agent queue to check whether it can see the roles, and add your account into the two groups.

Or, try to create a new agent queue to see whether you can see the roles, and deploy a new agent.

Comment: Try to select All Queues and then add your account to Administrator group. And check all permissions described on website: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/index

Comment: I have the same problem on "All queues" item, no roles appear in the roles tab

Comment: Is your account in Build Administrators group?

Comment: No, but I am in the "Team Foundation Administrators" group and the "Project Collection Administrators" group

Comment: @EduardoWada Check your account on TFS Web Access to see which groups it belongs to, and also check the permission of the groups you belong to.